# Pitot static-Tube with holes about 8 holes around the tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have two types of Pitot static tube, both of them with 8 holes, however the location of the holes is different, 1.5 and 6.2 cm from the entering section to tube. How does this location of the holes affect on the sensitivity of each tube. I have got results in experiment and the closer one to the entering section was more sensitive.

thank you for helping,

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of these holes is to take the static pressure side of the measurement. Their position and number have little effect on the sensitivity of the device.

There is probably some other difference in the design, maintenance or operation of the devices which accounts for the difference in sensitivity. For example : obstructions in the holes, or the quality of the transducer used to measure the pressure difference.

Comment: Yeah. Other possible considerations: Still work in the presence of ice. Be more accurate at different yaw and pitch angles.